# Use Apps Script URLFetchApp to access Google Datastore Data

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-datastore, urlfetch

I want to experiment with Google Datastore via Apps Script because I have a current solution based on Google sheets that runs into timeout issues inherent in constantly transacting with Drive files. I've created a test project in Google cloud with a service account and enabled library **MZx5DzNPsYjVyZaR67xXJQai_d-phDA33**
 (cGoa) to handle the Oauth2 work. I followed the guide to start it up [here](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/goa) and got all the pertinent confirmation that it works with my token (and that removing the token throws an 'authentication failed prompt').

Now I want to start with a basic query to display the one entity I already put in. I can use the API Explorer [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/runQuery) and run this query body:

```
{
   "query": {}
}
```

and get this result:

```
{
 "batch": {
"entityResultType": "FULL",
"entityResults": [
  {
    "entity": {
      "key": {
        "partitionId": {
          "projectId": "project-id-5200707333336492774"
        },
        "path": [
          {
            "kind": "Transaction",
            "id": "5629499534213120"
          }
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "CommentIn": {
          "stringValue": "My First Test Transaction"
        },
        "Status": {
          "stringValue": "Closed"
        },
        "auditStatus": {
          "stringValue": "Logged"
        },
        "User": {
          "stringValue": "John Doe"
        },
        "Start": {
          "timestampValue": "2017-08-17T18:07:04.681Z"
        },
        "CommentOut": {
          "stringValue": "Done for today!"
        },
        "End": {
          "timestampValue": "2017-08-17T20:07:38.058Z"
        },
        "Period": {
          "stringValue": "08/16/2017-08/31/2017"
        }
      }
    },
    "cursor": "CkISPGogc35whh9qZWN0LWlkLTUyMDA3MDcwODA1MDY0OTI3NzRyGAsSC1RyYW5zYWN0aW9uGICAgICAgIAKDBgAIAA=",
    "version": "1503004124243000"
  }
],
"endCursor": "CkISPGogc35wcm9qZWN0LWlkLTUyMDAxxDcwODA1MDY0OTI3NzRyGAsSC1RyYW5zYWN0aW9uGICAgICAgIAKDBgAIAA=",
"moreResults": "NO_MORE_RESULTS"
 }
}
```

I try to do the same thing with this code:

```
 function doGet(e)
  {
   var goa = cGoa.GoaApp.createGoa('Oauth2-Service-Account',

  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()).execute(e);
    if(goa.hasToken()) {var token = goa.getToken();}

      var payload = {"query":{}}
            ; 

        var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id-5200707333336492774:runQuery', 
                     {
                      method: "POST", 
                       headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + goa.getToken()}, 
         muteHttpExceptions : true,
                       payload: payload
                     });



        Logger.log(result.getBlob().getDataAsString());
          }
```

and get this error in the logger:

```
   "error": {
     "code": 400,
     "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"query\": Cannot bind query parameter. 'query' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types.",
     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
     "details": [
       {
         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
         "fieldViolations": [
           {
             "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"query\": Cannot bind query parameter. 'query' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types."
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

If I try to use another word such as 'resource' or 'GqlQuery', I get this error:

```
  "error": {
     "code": 400,
     "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"GqlQuery\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'GqlQuery' could not be found in request message.",
     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
     "details": [
       {
         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
         "fieldViolations": [
           {
             "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"GqlQuery\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'GqlQuery' could not be found in request message."
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

I can't tell from the API Documentation what my syntax is supposed to be. Can anyone tell me how to compile a functional request body from Apps Script to Datastore?

Comment: Also: Running the query with an empty body Creates this response:                         "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "one of fields Query.query and Query.gql_query must be set",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the **contentType** of your payload as well as stringify your JSON payload as follows:

```
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    'https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id-5200707333336492774:runQuery',
    {
        'method':'post',
        'contentType':'application/json',
        'headers': {authorization: "Bearer " + goa.getToken()},
        'payload':JSON.stringify(payload)
    }
);
```

Comment: You did it, Dimu Designs! Thanks! It works good now!  So, is there a reference for this API that I didn't find? Google's API page didn't make that clear...

Comment: Sending requests and receiving responses over HTTP is universal to web development in general so the Apps Script documentation kinda glosses over it. But it does cover the topic a wee bit under the UrlFetchApp documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Comment: If you really want to delve deeper into the topic you can try tackling the following guide:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-the-protocol-every-web-developer-must-know-part-1--net-31177

It's a lot to chew on but you'll come away with a better understanding of how http works once you muddle through it.